# How to reset par(mfrow) in R

Tags: r, plot, reset, r-base-graphics

I set par(mfrow =c(1,2)) and now everytime I plot it shows splits it into 2 plots.
How can I reset this to only show one plot.

Thanks so much.

Comment: You can also reset it by closing the graph.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can reset the mfrow parameter

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Comment: @akz More generally, keep in mind that each plotting device has it's own separate `par` settings. So if you are generating plots interactively in the console and you change some settings using `par(foo = bar)`, you can always start over by calling `dev.off()` and create plots on a new device.

Comment: that's super useful. Thanks Joran.

Comment: another useful idiom is `oldparams <- par(mfrow=c(2,1)); [do stuff]; par(oldparams)`

Comment: Just a heads up for anyone trying this in a R script. Sometimes there will be functions (e.g. `NbClust`) which will generate graphs for you, they actually change the value of `mfrow` and leave it; therefore your next graphs will be side-by-side.

Just add `par(mfrow=c(1, 1))` after running those functions and you're good to go.

Answer (score 41):

You can reset the plot by doing this:

```
dev.off()
```

Comment: This works when working interactively but can break document generation systems like knitr\pandoc.

Comment: If you do not check if there is anything to close, you will have an error. It is better to use:            `if(dev.cur() > 1) dev.off()`

Comment: We can use `graphics.off()` to close all devices at once.

Answer (score 0):

Both `dev.off()` and `graphics.off()` works fine for me.
Good luck!